# SSRS Row visibility where lookup, parameters are involved

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a table which should hide the rows based on the below conditions -

1. Parameter value = Active, show rows with Active status
2. Parameter value = Matured, show rows with Matured status
3. Parameter value = Active and Matured, show all the records.

I have implemented the below for now -

```
=iif(parameter!activeormatured.value="Active",
    TRIM(LOOKUP(Fields.ProductID.Value,Fields.ProductID.Value, Fields.ProductActiveflag.value, "Datasetname")) = "Active", 
    iif(parameter!activeormatured.value = "Matured", 
        TRIM(LOOKUP(Fields.ProductID.Value, Fields.ProductID.Value, Fields.ProductActiveflag.value, "Datasetname")) = "Matured",
        False)
        )
    )
```

The above expression works only for the scenario Parameter value= Active and Matured.

Answer (score 0):

Array.IndexOf can be used with multi-value paramters to check the selected parameters for a given value.

This should return a TRUE value when the Lookup matches a value in the Parameter.

```
=Array.IndexOf(Parameters!activeormatured.Value, 
                TRIM(LOOKUP(Fields.ProductID.Value, Fields.ProductID.Value, Fields.ProductActiveflag.value, "Datasetname"))
                ) > -1
```

If it's not a multi-value parameter but a single value with both values, you can use the InStr function which returns the location of a string in another string. If it doesn't find the string, it returns zero.

```
=InStr(Parameters!activeormatured.Value, 
       TRIM(LOOKUP(Fields.ProductID.Value, Fields.ProductID.Value, Fields.ProductActiveflag.value, "Datasetname"))
       ) > 0
```

Comment: Hi , this is not a multi value parameter. Sorry, I did not mention that. Its a single select, with 3 values - Active, Matured, Active and Matured. I suppose Array.IndexOf does not work with Single select, right?

Comment: @Geethu - I added an answer for a single value parameter with both values.